# remove duplicate separator pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following columns that I am reading from a excel sheet

```
CM              FOTO 1              FOTO 2              FOTO 3              FOTO 4           
some text some  744905_L050_01.jpg  NaN                 744905_B001_01.jpg  NaN
some text some  NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN
some text some  621059_W034_01.jpg  621059_W034_02.jpg  621059_W034_03.jpg  NaN     
some text some  NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN
```

Then I am writing a new csv file, and creating following columns:

```
df_["DESCRIPTION"] = df["CM "]
df_["IMAGES_URL"] = df[["FOTO 1 ", "FOTO 2 ", "FOTO 3 ", "FOTO 4 "]].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep='|'), axis=1)
df_["WAREHOUSE"] = "D"
```

finally I am storing it in a csv file and using semicolon as separator:

`df_.to_csv('path/my_file.csv', encoding = 'utf-8', index=False, sep=';')`

The output looks as follows:

```
DESCRIPTION;IMAGES_URL;WAREHOUSE
some text some;744905_L050_01.jpg|744905_B001_01.jpg;D
some text some;;D
some text some;621059_W034_01.jpg|621059_W034_02.jpg|621059_W034_03.jpg;D
some text some;;D
```

However if all four Foto columns have `NaN` values, it writes double `;;` into the csv file.
How can I remove the double semicolons and replace it with only one semicolon?

Comment: You have a "double semicolon" where you do not have a foto in the dataframe. The problem should be solved there.

Comment: How can I solve that? I have already tried to replace ";;" with ";", but it didn't work out

Comment: Again, you have a ";;" (an empty column) because there is a missing value. There must be the same number of columns in each row of a CSV file. That's non-negotiable. You cannot have what you want - and why do you want it, in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you artificially replace the ";;" with a ";", you will have data from, say Foto 3 getting into the Foto 2 column. Is that really what you want? If not, you can just fill the NaNs with something else with:

```py
df_.fillna('No foto', inplace=True)
```